custom python script as azure end point?
what would be the code for scoring.py on azure end point, for the following python function:
def predict(a):
    return a*a

Function saved as mlflow model >> mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path='./model', python_model=predict)
Any solutions please?
My guess..?
#--scoring.py--#
def init():
    global model
    global input_schema
    model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "model")
    model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_path)

def run(raw_data):
    # Parse input data as a single value
    data = raw_data
    # Call your Python function
    predictions = model.predict(data)  # Replace with your actual function
    return predictions

I tried many variations of the scoring file but it fails to generate predict outputs

You are in the right way. Instead of calling model.predict(data) you pass the data to you custom function.
import os
import logging
import json
import numpy
import joblib


def init():
    """
    This function is called when the container is initialized/started, typically after create/update of the deployment.
    You can write the logic here to perform init operations like caching the model in memory
    """
    global model
    # AZUREML_MODEL_DIR is an environment variable created during deployment.
    # It is the path to the model folder (./azureml-models/$MODEL_NAME/$VERSION)
    model_path = os.path.join(
        os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "sklearn_regression_model.pkl"
    )
    # deserialize the model file back into a sklearn model
    model = joblib.load(model_path)
    logging.info("Init complete")

def predict(data):
    #Do the changes to your data and return whatever you need to also you can use model.predict
    return results

def run(raw_data):
    """
    This function is called for every invocation of the endpoint to perform the actual scoring/prediction.
    In the example we extract the data from the json input and call the scikit-learn model's predict()
    method and return the result back
    """
    logging.info("Request received")
    data = json.loads(raw_data)["data"]
    data = numpy.array(data)
    result = predict(data)
    logging.info("Request processed")
    return result.tolist()

Here, calling predict function passing the data which is numpy array.
In predict function you do changes and predict the results using model.predict.
refer this sample file
Next, you can also add the input and output schema that you required.
There is a decorator input_schema, output_schema you can use for run function.
input_sample = np.array([[10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]])
output_sample = np.array([3726.995])

@input_schema('data', NumpyParameterType(input_sample))
@output_schema(NumpyParameterType(output_sample))
def run(data):
    try:
        result = model.predict(data)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        return error

Here, it validates the input to be of numpy 2D array and output numpy array.
Refer this stack solution for more information.
